# iPhone 6+ Scrollview Frame Shifts

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a ScrollView set up with what I've come to understand is the only way of making it behave using autolayout:

```
View (UIView *)
 -> ScrollView (UIScrollView *)
     -> ContentView (UIView *)
```

I have the ScrollView constrained to the bounds of the outer view, and the ContentView constrained to the ScrollView, so that as it grows the ScrollView does too.  I also have an Equal Widths constraint from the ContentView to the outer View, to ensure that it grows to the maximum width (thanks, iPhone 6/+!)

Now:  With iPhone 6+, and the above described setup, I have an issue where some time after viewWillAppear the frame isn't set properly.  Instead of (0 0; 414 672) as I might expect I'm getting (4 0; 406 672).  The X is coming in, and the width isn't being set to the theoretical maximum (by my equal widths constraint).  All other devices on the XCode Simulator function as expected (4, 5, 5s, 6), with the ScrollView filling the screen.